# Class 'Aws\S3\S3Client' not found after building app to AWS yii2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have uploaded the application into AWS, the code is recognizable in HostGator and localhost, but when I upload it to AWS, it shows that the file is not found. I downloaded the uploaded files and checked that the files are there but still nothing. any thoughts why this issue keeps showing for me?

this is the page that shows the error

```
<?php

/**
 * S3 Upload component for Yii2 framework
 *
 * S3 is a wrapper for AWS SDK for PHP (@link https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php)
 * This wrapper contains minimal functionality as there is only so much I want to allow access to from the Yii public end
 *
 * @version 0.1
 *
 * @author Maxim Gordienko (3dmaxpayne.com)
 */

namespace yii\mag;

use Yii;

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
use yii\base\Component;
use yii\base\Exception;
use yii\mag\S3\FileUpload;

class S3 extends Component
{

    private $_s3;
    public $key;    // AWS Access key
    public $secret; // AWS Secret key
    public $bucket;
     public $region;
       public $version='2006-03-01';
    public $lastError="";
  private $_folder        = '######';
    private $_treeStructure = true;
    private $_hashFilename  = true;
    private $_fsPath        = '########';
    private $_fsUrl         = '##############';
    private $_ACL           = '########';
    /**
     * Return S3 Client instance
     * @return S3Client
     */
    private function getInstance()
    {
        if ($this->_s3 === NULL){
        $this->_s3=$this->connect();}
        return $this->_s3;
    }

    /**
     * Instance the S3 object
     */
    public function connect()
    {
        if ( $this->key === NULL || $this->secret === NULL )
            throw new Exception('S3 Keys are not set.');

        $this->_s3 = S3Client::factory([
           'credentials' => ['key' => $this->key, 'secret' => $this->secret],  //'key'    => ,
            //'secret' => ,
            'version' => $this->version,
            'region'=>$this->region,
            'bucket'=>$this->bucket,
        ]);

        return  $this->_s3 ;
    }

    /**
     * Upload file to S3
     * @param string $file path to file on local server
     * @param string $fileName name of file on Amazon. It can include directories.
     * @param null $bucket bucket name. By default use bucket from config
     */
    public function upload($file, $fileName, $bucket)
    {

            $bucket = $this->bucket;


         //$aws = Yii::$app->awssdk->getAwsSdk();
     //$s3 =new S3 ;
             //$s3=$s3->createS3();

        if(!empty($fileName)){
        try {
            /*$s3->putObject(array(
                'Bucket' => $bucket,
                //'SourceFile' => $fileName,
                'Key'    => basename($file),
                'Body'   => $file,
                'SourceFile'   => $file->tempName,
             'ContentType'  => $file->type,
                'ACL'    => 'public-read',
                'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',

            ));*/

              $s3 = $this->getInstance();
              $upload= $s3->putObject(
            array(
             'Bucket'       => $this->bucket,
             'Key'          => $this->getUploadFolder().$this->getFilename($fileName),
             'SourceFile'   => $fileName->tempName,
             'ContentType'  => $fileName->type,
             'ACL'          => $this->_ACL,
             'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
            )
        );
        //var_dump($upload);die;
        //return $upload->get(['ObjectURL']);


            //return 1;//$upload['ObjectURL'];

           /* $photo = UploadedFile::getInstance($file, $fileName); 
$uploader = new FileUpload(FileUpload::S_S3, [
    'version' => $this->version,
    'region' => $this->region,
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => $this->key,
        'secret' => $this->secret
    ],
    'bucket' => $this->bucket
]);*/
        //return 1;
        } catch (S3Exception $e) {

            return 0;
            //echo "There was an error uploading the file.\n";
        }}else{return 0;}
    }

    /**
     * Use for call another functions of S3Client
     * @param string $func
     * @param array $args
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \yii\base\Exception
     */
      final function getTreeStructureMap()
    {
        return substr(md5(microtime()), mt_rand(0, 30), 2).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.substr(md5(microtime()), mt_rand(0, 30), 2);

    }
    final function getUploadFolder()
    {
        return $this->_folder.'/';

    }

    final function getFilename($file){



        //$fileName  = $file->name;
        $fileName= str_replace([" ", "."], "_", $file->name).date('_Y_m_d_H_i').'.'.$file->extension;
        $pathParts = pathinfo($fileName);

        return  $fileName;

    }

    public function __call($func, $args )
    {
        $s3 = $this->getInstance();
        return call_user_func([$s3, $func], $args[0]);
    }
}
```

what should I do?

Comment: Check [yii2tech/file-storage](https://github.com/yii2tech/file-storage)

Comment: @Bizley my issue is with the files that are not found in the server. the app can't see the files